# cfdocument Tag Support in Standard vs. Enterprise

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

As we upgrade from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11, my university is trying to determine whether ColdFusion 11 Standard will be adequate for us, or whether we need Enterprise.

The biggest issue seems to be the `<cfdocument format="PDF">` tag. In the ColdFusion product comaparison (http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-family/buying-guide.html), it says that "PDF file generation from HTML" is available in Enterprise, but "restricted" in Standard.

To my mind, "restricted" is not the same thing as "unavailable" -- but I have been unable to find any elaboration on the Adobe site or elsewhere about what "restricted" means (and what the restrictions are). And though I have attempted to get the information from a sales representative at Adobe, I have so far been unable to make contact with anyone who is able to answer the question.

Does anyone here know how this tag behaves in ColdFusion 11 Standard, or have a copy of Standard on which they could execute the following simple test?

```
<cfdocument format="PDF">
  <p>Hello World.</p>
</cfdocument>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says on the bottom of the same link,

*"**Restricted features** in ColdFusion Standard Edition: Enterprise features run through the Enterprise Feature Router (EFR). These features run in the Standard edition. However, all features running through the EFR are limited to one shared simultaneous request."*

Hope this answers, your query.

Comment: Thank you, Anit. I don't know how I missed that in all of my searching, but somehow I overlooked it. Much appreciated!